# Rename all '.' to '_' in a filename except for the extension

Tags: regex, linux, bash, rename, file-rename

I am trying to create a script that replaces all the "." occurences in a filename with "_". For example when I try to replace all the " " symbols I use this:

```
rename 'y/ /_/' '{}' file
# test 1.2.jpg -> test_1.2.jpg
```

Which works fine, but when I try to do it with the "." symbol the extension also changes:

```
rename 'y/./_/' '{}' file
# test 1.2.jpg -> test 1_2_jpg
```

How can I rename the file without changing the extension (when there is one)?

Comment: `when there is one` -- and what logic would be applied to figure _if there is one_?

Comment: How would you define "extension", if not the part behind the last "."..

Comment: @devnull well for example the `file` command could be used to determine the mime-type, and then a regex comparison between that and the string after the last point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to replace all dots before the very last dot:

```
rename 's/\.(?=[^.]*\.)/_/g' '{}'
```

OR using negative lookahead:

```
rename 's/\.(?![^.]*$)/_/g' '{}'
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the filename `test.1.2.jpg` gets converted to `test_1.2.jpg`

Comment: And what about files like .tar.gz? :) <\troll>

Comment: @ Nippey, good question, but I don't think OP will think of that.

Comment: Actually you just needed `g` switch, its edited now. Can you try it?

Comment: @anubhava yes it works! Except for the `.tar.gz` as @Nippey pointed out, but I can live with that for now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, yes I agree that `.tar.gz` will be tricky since theere are 2 dots in the extension. May be better to use `.tgz` for the same :)

Comment: @anubhava: Yep. Or extend the regexp to handle such expections. Just kidding! ^^ .tgz is nice!

Answer (score 0):

rename -n 's/ \.(?=.*\.)//g' * : -n no action.
To actually make changes remove -n.